# Include error in embebed desing STM32 with VScode

Tags: include, stm32, firmware

I've working in firmware programming with STM32 and VSCode.

My actual situation in extensions in VScode are: C/C++, cmake, cmake-tools, STM32 VS Code extension, and cortex-debug.
As "STM32 VS Code extension" I've intalled the program `STM32CubeIDE` and `STM32CubeMX`.

I've created the project by `STM32CubeMX` and I modify my `CMakeFileList.txt`.

This is my project estructure:

```
TFT_STM32
├─ .cproject
├─ .mxproject
├─ .project
├─ .settings
│  ├─ language.settings.xml
│  └─ stm32cubeide.project.prefs
├─ .vs
│  └─ launch.vs.json
├─ .vscode
│  ├─ extensions.json
│  ├─ launch.json
│  ├─ settings.json
│  └─ tasks.json
├─ build
│  └─ release
│     └─ build
│        ├─ .cmake
│        │  └─ api
│        │     └─ v1
│        │        ├─ query
│        │        │  └─ client-vscode
│        │        │     └─ query.json
│        │        └─ reply
│        │           ├─ cache-v2-45a28c30da73a9f50c5f.json
│        │           ├─ cmakeFiles-v1-41116acbc216fa81de8e.json
│        │           ├─ codemodel-v2-45a7f5e4f1b4419b5be9.json
│        │           ├─ directory-.-Release-d0094a50bb2071803777.json
│        │           ├─ index-2023-12-04T11-32-04-0433.json
│        │           ├─ target-TFT_STM32-Release-74a645a5d2f455f874dc.json
│        │           └─ toolchains-v1-7576d739f273a178801d.json
│        ├─ .ninja_deps
│        ├─ .ninja_log
│        ├─ build.ninja
│        ├─ CMakeCache.txt
│        ├─ CMakeFiles
│        │  ├─ 3.20.0
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeASMCompiler.cmake
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeSystem.cmake
│        │  │  ├─ CompilerIdASM
│        │  │  ├─ CompilerIdC
│        │  │  │  ├─ CMakeCCompilerId.c
│        │  │  │  ├─ CMakeCCompilerId.o
│        │  │  │  └─ tmp
│        │  │  └─ CompilerIdCXX
│        │  │     ├─ CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│        │  │     ├─ CMakeCXXCompilerId.o
│        │  │     └─ tmp
│        │  ├─ 3.28.0-rc5
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeASMCompiler.cmake
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│        │  │  ├─ CMakeSystem.cmake
│        │  │  ├─ CompilerIdASM
│        │  │  ├─ CompilerIdC
│        │  │  │  ├─ CMakeCCompilerId.c
│        │  │  │  ├─ CMakeCCompilerId.o
│        │  │  │  └─ tmp
│        │  │  └─ CompilerIdCXX
│        │  │     ├─ CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│        │  │     ├─ CMakeCXXCompilerId.o
│        │  │     └─ tmp
│        │  ├─ cmake.check_cache
│        │  ├─ CMakeConfigureLog.yaml
│        │  ├─ CMakeError.log
│        │  ├─ CMakeOutput.log
│        │  ├─ CMakeTmp
│        │  ├─ pkgRedirects
│        │  ├─ rules.ninja
│        │  ├─ TargetDirectories.txt
│        │  └─ TFT_STM32.dir
│        │     ├─ CMakeFiles
│        │     │  ├─ 3.20.0
│        │     │  │  └─ CompilerIdC
│        │     │  └─ 3.28.0-rc5
│        │     │     └─ CompilerIdC
│        │     ├─ Core
│        │     │  ├─ Src
│        │     │  │  ├─ main.c.obj
│        │     │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c.obj
│        │     │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_it.c.obj
│        │     │  │  ├─ syscalls.c.obj
│        │     │  │  ├─ sysmem.c.obj
│        │     │  │  └─ system_stm32f4xx.c.obj
│        │     │  ├─ st7735
│        │     │  └─ Startup
│        │     │     └─ startup_stm32f411ceux.s.obj
│        │     ├─ Drivers
│        │     │  └─ STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver
│        │     │     └─ Src
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_exti.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c_ex.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim.c.obj
│        │     │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.c.obj
│        │     │        └─ stm32f4xx_ll_usb.c.obj
│        │     ├─ Middlewares
│        │     │  └─ ST
│        │     │     └─ STM32_USB_Device_Library
│        │     │        ├─ Class
│        │     │        │  └─ CDC
│        │     │        │     └─ Src
│        │     │        │        └─ usbd_cdc.c.obj
│        │     │        └─ Core
│        │     │           └─ Src
│        │     │              ├─ usbd_core.c.obj
│        │     │              ├─ usbd_ctlreq.c.obj
│        │     │              └─ usbd_ioreq.c.obj
│        │     └─ USB_DEVICE
│        │        ├─ App
│        │        │  ├─ usbd_cdc_if.c.obj
│        │        │  ├─ usbd_desc.c.obj
│        │        │  └─ usb_device.c.obj
│        │        └─ Target
│        │           └─ usbd_conf.c.obj
│        ├─ cmake_install.cmake
│        ├─ TFT_STM32.bin
│        ├─ TFT_STM32.elf
│        └─ TFT_STM32.hex
├─ cmake
│  ├─ gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake
│  └─ st-project.cmake
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ CMakePresets.json
├─ Core
│  ├─ Inc
│  │  ├─ fonts.h
│  │  ├─ main.h
│  │  ├─ st7735.h
│  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h
│  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_it.h
│  │  └─ testimg.h
│  ├─ Src
│  │  ├─ fonts.c
│  │  ├─ main.c
│  │  ├─ st7735.c
│  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c
│  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_it.c
│  │  ├─ syscalls.c
│  │  ├─ sysmem.c
│  │  └─ system_stm32f4xx.c
│  └─ Startup
│     └─ startup_stm32f411ceux.s
├─ Debug
│  ├─ Core
│  │  ├─ Src
│  │  │  ├─ fonts.cyclo
│  │  │  ├─ fonts.d
│  │  │  ├─ fonts.o
│  │  │  ├─ fonts.su
│  │  │  ├─ main.cyclo
│  │  │  ├─ main.d
│  │  │  ├─ main.o
│  │  │  ├─ main.su
│  │  │  ├─ st7735.cyclo
│  │  │  ├─ st7735.d
│  │  │  ├─ st7735.o
│  │  │  ├─ st7735.su
│  │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_msp.cyclo
│  │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_msp.d
│  │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o
│  │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_msp.su
│  │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_it.cyclo
│  │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_it.d
│  │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_it.o
│  │  │  ├─ stm32f4xx_it.su
│  │  │  ├─ subdir.mk
│  │  │  ├─ syscalls.cyclo
│  │  │  ├─ syscalls.d
│  │  │  ├─ syscalls.o
│  │  │  ├─ syscalls.su
│  │  │  ├─ sysmem.cyclo
│  │  │  ├─ sysmem.d
│  │  │  ├─ sysmem.o
│  │  │  ├─ sysmem.su
│  │  │  ├─ system_stm32f4xx.cyclo
│  │  │  ├─ system_stm32f4xx.d
│  │  │  ├─ system_stm32f4xx.o
│  │  │  └─ system_stm32f4xx.su
│  │  └─ Startup
│  │     ├─ startup_stm32f411ceux.d
│  │     ├─ startup_stm32f411ceux.o
│  │     └─ subdir.mk
│  ├─ Drivers
│  │  └─ STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver
│  │     └─ Src
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_exti.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_exti.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_exti.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_exti.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c_ex.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c_ex.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c_ex.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_i2c_ex.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_spi.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_spi.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_spi.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_spi.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.su
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_usb.cyclo
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_usb.d
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o
│  │        ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_usb.su
│  │        └─ subdir.mk
│  ├─ makefile
│  ├─ Middlewares
│  │  └─ ST
│  │     └─ STM32_USB_Device_Library
│  │        ├─ Class
│  │        │  └─ CDC
│  │        │     └─ Src
│  │        │        ├─ subdir.mk
│  │        │        ├─ usbd_cdc.cyclo
│  │        │        ├─ usbd_cdc.d
│  │        │        ├─ usbd_cdc.o
│  │        │        └─ usbd_cdc.su
│  │        └─ Core
│  │           └─ Src
│  │              ├─ subdir.mk
│  │              ├─ usbd_core.cyclo
│  │              ├─ usbd_core.d
│  │              ├─ usbd_core.o
│  │              ├─ usbd_core.su
│  │              ├─ usbd_ctlreq.cyclo
│  │              ├─ usbd_ctlreq.d
│  │              ├─ usbd_ctlreq.o
│  │              ├─ usbd_ctlreq.su
│  │              ├─ usbd_ioreq.cyclo
│  │              ├─ usbd_ioreq.d
│  │              ├─ usbd_ioreq.o
│  │              └─ usbd_ioreq.su
│  ├─ objects.list
│  ├─ objects.mk
│  ├─ sources.mk
│  ├─ TFT_STM32.elf
│  ├─ TFT_STM32.list
│  ├─ TFT_STM32.map
│  └─ USB_DEVICE
│     ├─ App
│     │  ├─ subdir.mk
│     │  ├─ usbd_cdc_if.cyclo
│     │  ├─ usbd_cdc_if.d
│     │  ├─ usbd_cdc_if.o
│     │  ├─ usbd_cdc_if.su
│     │  ├─ usbd_desc.cyclo
│     │  ├─ usbd_desc.d
│     │  ├─ usbd_desc.o
│     │  ├─ usbd_desc.su
│     │  ├─ usb_device.cyclo
│     │  ├─ usb_device.d
│     │  ├─ usb_device.o
│     │  └─ usb_device.su
│     └─ Target
│        ├─ subdir.mk
│        ├─ usbd_conf.cyclo
│        ├─ usbd_conf.d
│        ├─ usbd_conf.o
│        └─ usbd_conf.su
├─ Drivers
│  ├─ CMSIS
│  │  ├─ Device
│  │  │  └─ ST
│  │  │     └─ STM32F4xx
│  │  │        ├─ Include
│  │  │        │  ├─ stm32f411xe.h
│  │  │        │  ├─ stm32f4xx.h
│  │  │        │  └─ system_stm32f4xx.h
│  │  │        ├─ LICENSE.txt
│  │  │        └─ Source
│  │  │           └─ Templates
│  │  ├─ Include
│  │  │  ├─ cmsis_armcc.h
│  │  │  ├─ cmsis_armclang.h
│  │  │  ├─ cmsis_compiler.h
│  │  │  ├─ cmsis_gcc.h
│  │  │  ├─ cmsis_iccarm.h
│  │  │  ├─ cmsis_version.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_armv8mbl.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_armv8mml.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_cm0.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_cm0plus.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_cm1.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_cm23.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_cm3.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_cm33.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_cm4.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_cm7.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_sc000.h
│  │  │  ├─ core_sc300.h
│  │  │  ├─ mpu_armv7.h
│  │  │  ├─ mpu_armv8.h
│  │  │  └─ tz_context.h
│  │  └─ LICENSE.txt
│  └─ STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver
│     ├─ Inc
│     │  ├─ Legacy
│     │  │  └─ stm32_hal_legacy.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_def.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_exti.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_gpio_ex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_spi.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_bus.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_cortex.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_dma.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_exti.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_gpio.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_pwr.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_rcc.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_spi.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_system.h
│     │  ├─ stm32f4xx_ll_usb.h
│     │  └─ stm32f4xx_ll_utils.h
│     ├─ LICENSE.txt
│     └─ Src
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_exti.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_spi.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim.c
│        ├─ stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.c
│        └─ stm32f4xx_ll_usb.c
├─ Middlewares
│  └─ ST
│     └─ STM32_USB_Device_Library
│        ├─ Class
│        │  └─ CDC
│        │     ├─ Inc
│        │     │  └─ usbd_cdc.h
│        │     └─ Src
│        │        └─ usbd_cdc.c
│        ├─ Core
│        │  ├─ Inc
│        │  │  ├─ usbd_core.h
│        │  │  ├─ usbd_ctlreq.h
│        │  │  ├─ usbd_def.h
│        │  │  └─ usbd_ioreq.h
│        │  └─ Src
│        │     ├─ usbd_core.c
│        │     ├─ usbd_ctlreq.c
│        │     └─ usbd_ioreq.c
│        └─ LICENSE.txt
├─ rutasC.txt
├─ rutasH.txt
├─ STM32F411CEUX_FLASH.ld
├─ STM32F411CEUX_RAM.ld
├─ TFT_STM32.ioc
├─ USB_DEVICE
│  ├─ App
│  │  ├─ usbd_cdc_if.c
│  │  ├─ usbd_cdc_if.h
│  │  ├─ usbd_desc.c
│  │  ├─ usbd_desc.h
│  │  ├─ usb_device.c
│  │  └─ usb_device.h
│  └─ Target
│     ├─ usbd_conf.c
│     └─ usbd_conf.h
└─ vcpkg-configuration.json
```

In other hand, here I have my `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

# Setup compiler settings
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD                11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED       ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS              ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD              20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED     ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS            ON)
set(PROJ_PATH                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
message("Build type: "              ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

#
# Core project settings
#
project(TFT_STM32)
enable_language(C CXX ASM)

#
# Core MCU flags, CPU, instruction set and FPU setup
# Needs to be set properly for your MCU
#
set(CPU_PARAMETERS
    -mthumb

    # This needs attention to properly set for used MCU
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
    -mfloat-abi=hard
)

# Set linker script
set(linker_script_SRC               ${PROJ_PATH}/STM32F411CEUX_FLASH.ld)
set(EXECUTABLE                      ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

#
# List of source files to compile
#
set(sources_SRCS
    # Put here your source files, one in each line, relative to CMakeLists.txt file location
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Src/main.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Src/fonts.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Src/st7735.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Src/syscalls.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Src/sysmem.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/USB_DEVICE/App/usb_device.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/USB_DEVICE/App/usbd_cdc_if.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/USB_DEVICE/App/usbd_desc.c
    ${PROJ_PATH}/USB_DEVICE/Target
)

#
# Include directories
#
set(include_path_DIRS
    # Put here your include dirs, one in each line, relative to CMakeLists.txt file location
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Core/Inc/
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Drivers/CMSIS/Include
    ${PROJ_PATH}/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
    ${PROJ_PATH}/USB_DEVICE/App
    ${PROJ_PATH}/USB_DEVICE/Target
)

#
# Symbols definition
#
set(symbols_SYMB
    # Put here your symbols (preprocessor defines), one in each line
    # Encapsulate them with double quotes for safety purpose
)

# Executable files
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE} ${sources_SRCS})

# Include paths
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE ${include_path_DIRS})

# Project symbols
target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE ${symbols_SYMB})

# Compiler options
target_compile_options(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    ${CPU_PARAMETERS}
    -Wall
    -Wextra
    -Wpedantic
    -Wno-unused-parameter
    # Full debug configuration
    -Og -g3 -ggdb
)

# Linker options
target_link_options(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    -T${linker_script_SRC}
    ${CPU_PARAMETERS}
    -Wl,-Map=${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.map
    --specs=nosys.specs
    -u _printf_float                # STDIO float formatting support
    -Wl,--start-group
    -lc
    -lm
    -lstdc++
    -lsupc++
    -Wl,--end-group
    -Wl,--print-memory-usage
)

# Execute post-build to print size
add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_SIZE} $<TARGET_FILE:${EXECUTABLE}>
)

# Convert output to hex and binary
add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex $<TARGET_FILE:${EXECUTABLE}> ${EXECUTABLE}.hex
)

# Convert to bin file -> add conditional check?
add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary $<TARGET_FILE:${EXECUTABLE}> ${EXECUTABLE}.bin
)
```

My include problem is with `#include "usb_device.h"` and... I don't know why, this archives is in `USB_DEVICE` and I don't undertand why the rest of libraries and includes ara fine, but this no.

Thanks a lot

I've been modifying my includes list in `CMakeList.txt` and I fixed all my include problems, but I can't fix this

Comment: have you tried putting ```usb_device.h``` in ```Core/Inc``` folder and ```usb_device.c``` in ```Core/SRC``` folder?

Comment: Yes, and still cant´t build it. I've "found" another way to work with it with another extension, but i cant't make this "natural way"